# Magento TopLinks as dropdown on hover

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm using Magento 1.7 Community and wanting to have the toplinks as a drop down like in this template:

http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#magento-themes.joomlart.com/jm_wall

but not sure how I go about it. I know where the links are but they are in a php foreach loop

and I want them to be

- My Account

  - Wish List

  - Login

Comment: post some code as to what you have tried.

Comment: This is done only by CSS and JQuery.

Comment: I know how to do the css and jquery but the magento scritp puts the toplinks in a foreach li statement so what do i change to break the loop to have links as above

Answer (score 0):

links handle by xml file layout->customer.xml
creating new module with block as your jquery navigation , override in module xml& remove tag from customer.xml this tips may be help you
also any new idea kindly reply me